# generate a Jar with IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, manifest, artifacts

i've created a .jar with Intellij, but the final product manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation)
```

In my Ide the manifest code is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Grafica.ProvaSchermata
```

Why during the  artifacts building the manifest change?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

i've changed the file pom.xml , with  tag. :

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Grafica.ProvaSchermata</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```